# Fetch cognito user details using event in Python

Tags: javascript, python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I want to fetch currently login in Cognito user details in python,

I got some idea that I need to call get_id() API, but here I need 3 parameters i.e. accountid, identity pool id, login maps and in login maps, I need JWT Token which I am generating in my Javascript code which is used to authenticate users that has to be imported here.

If it is possible to get through events, I have no idea of using that, But I need in Python, Reason behind this is I am automatically tagging the resources created by Cognito Users with their UsedID i.e. sub

Or I have to create that Login application in Python?

Update: I got something like Lambda Proxy Integration with API Gateways i can get event details, I have no idea oof using API Gateways, My application is just hosted on S3 Bucket

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution here is to simply use AWS Lambda triggers. In this case, the `Post Authentication Lambda Trigger` [1] ought to satisfy your use-case. You can obtain the Cognito user data in the Lambda event payload, and log it using whichever logging engine you would like to. In this case, you would not have the token in the Lambda payload, so you would need to make a discrete API call to fetch the JWT token.

AWS Lambda does support Python too, and I have written several significant lines of code in Lambda with Python. So, you could write your APIs in Python without any hitches.

If you are not okay with making a discrete Cognito API call and you would only like to modify some information in the Identity Token, you could look into the `pre-token generation Lambda trigger` [2].

You have mentioned using API Gateway with Lambda Proxy integration here, but it does not seem to be the right use-case to use the same.

## References

[1]. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-post-authentication.html

[2]. https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html

Comment: can't I create any event? I created Post Authentication Lambda and I got ID in CloudWatch logs, How do i fetch/use in Lambda back again?

Comment: You can use the ID directly in the code, should be a part of the JSON Lambda already has access to.